# Import results from another PC

Tags: pytest

Assuming I executed *pytest* on a remote host, export results to JSON (using pytest-json-report) and I transfer resulting JSON file to another PC. How can I "import" the results so the caller get the exact same output like he/she executed tests locally (with all pretty printing stuff)?

Comment: Why export to JSON?   You can also redirect output of the pretty printing stuff to a file, and transfer that file

Comment: @Luuk format is less relevant. I want basically to import results from another PC. I decided to test with JSON simply because there is existing plugin.

Comment: OK, I am pretty untrained on the area of `pytest`, but a short test ([Create your first test](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/getting-started.html)) made me think that you can create a readable output using `pytest >report.txt`. The file `report.txt` will contain readable output, in the same format as was shown on  screen.   But I am a bit lost when you say `import`, i did not see that on [Getting started](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/getting-started.html)

Comment: @Luuk I actually plan to import from multiple PCs, so would like to import programatically and "join" results (if possible)